# Windows Forms Modal Form Closes instantly when Base form is not Active

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a Winforms Application which should notify the user when something in a database changes. For that i use Sql-Dependencys, which works fine.
When the Dependency fires i am able to show a form with some Buttons so the user can decide what he wants to do.
After one Button i want to show a Dialog, but the first Dialog always gets closed instantly.
The only fix i found until now is restoring the base form and activating it, but that is not the solution i am looking for.
For the code i am doing the Following:

This Method gets called when something changes in the Database

```
Private Sub NutzerBenachrichtigen(Aenderung As Aenderung)
    If InvokeRequired Then
        Me.BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub()
                                             ErzeugeBenachrichtigung(Aenderung)
                                         End Sub))
    Else
        ErzeugeBenachrichtigung(Aenderung)
    End If
End Sub
```

This Method Displays the first form (HeadsUp is taken from this here :https://github.com/glm9637/MaterialWinforms/blob/master/MaterialWinforms/Controls/HeadsUp.cs)

```
    Private Sub ErzeugeBenachrichtigung(ByVal Aenderung As Aenderung)
    If Aenderung.istAktuellerBenutzer Then
        Dim objHeadsUp As New HeadsUp()
        objHeadsUp.Titel = "Neue Aenderung"
        If Aenderung.EventTyp.ToLower = "alter" Then
            objHeadsUp.Text = String.Format("Du hast etwas an {0} {1} {2} geändert. {3}Willst du etwas dazu schreiben?", _
                                   If(Aenderung.BetroffenesObjekt.EntitaetTyp.Name = New EntitaetTyp.Trigger().Name, "dem", "der"), _
                                   Aenderung.BetroffenesObjekt.EntitaetTyp.Name, Aenderung.BetroffenesObjekt.Name, vbNewLine)
        Else
            objHeadsUp.Text = String.Format("Du hast {0} {1} {2} erstellt. {3}Willst du etwas dazu schreiben?", _
                                  If(Aenderung.BetroffenesObjekt.EntitaetTyp.Name = New EntitaetTyp.Trigger().Name, "den", "die"), _
                                  Aenderung.BetroffenesObjekt.EntitaetTyp.Name, Aenderung.BetroffenesObjekt.Name, vbNewLine)
        End If
        objHeadsUp.Tag = Aenderung.BetroffenesObjekt
        Dim objButtonSchliessen = New MaterialFlatButton
        objButtonSchliessen.Tag = objHeadsUp
        objButtonSchliessen.Text = "Schliessen"
        AddHandler objButtonSchliessen.Click, AddressOf SchliesseHeadsUp
        objHeadsUp.Buttons.Add(objButtonSchliessen)
        Dim objButtonHistorie = New MaterialFlatButton
        objButtonHistorie.Tag = objHeadsUp
        objButtonHistorie.Text = "Historieneintrag"
        AddHandler objButtonHistorie.Click, AddressOf HistorienEintragHinzufuegen
        objHeadsUp.Buttons.Add(objButtonSchliessen)
        Dim objButtonDokumentation = New MaterialFlatButton
        objButtonDokumentation.Tag = objHeadsUp
        objButtonDokumentation.Text = "Dokumentation"
        AddHandler objButtonDokumentation.Click, AddressOf DokumentationBearbeiten
        objHeadsUp.Buttons.Add(objButtonSchliessen)
        objHeadsUp.Buttons.Add(objButtonHistorie)
        objHeadsUp.Buttons.Add(objButtonDokumentation)
        objHeadsUp.Show()

    ElseIf Aenderung.EventTyp = "CLOSE_MESSAGE" Then
        Dim objHeadsUp As New HeadsUp()
        objHeadsUp.Titel = "Achtung"
        objHeadsUp.Text = "Die Anwendung muss für eine Aktualisierung geschlossen werden."
        Dim objButtonSchliessen = New MaterialFlatButton
        objButtonSchliessen.Tag = objHeadsUp
        objButtonSchliessen.Text = "Anwendung Schliessen"
        AddHandler objButtonSchliessen.Click, AddressOf AnwendungSchliessen
        objHeadsUp.Buttons.Add(objButtonSchliessen)
        objHeadsUp.Show()
    Else
        If mtc_UebersichtTabControl.SelectedTab.Text = "Aenderung" Then
            mAenderungenUebersicht.Aktualisieren()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Finally when the "Historieneintrag" Button is pressed this Method gets called:

```
Private Sub HistorienEintragHinzufuegen(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim blnNachDialogVerstecken As Boolean = False
    Dim objFlatButton As MaterialFlatButton = sender
    Dim HeadsUp As HeadsUp = objFlatButton.Tag
    Dim Objekt As Entitaet = HeadsUp.Tag
    Dim objOldLocation As System.Drawing.Point = Location
    HeadsUp.Close()
    Dim objDialogContent As New HistorienEintrag()
    ''Hacky: Ansonsten wird der Dialog sofort geschlossen
    If WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Or Not Visible Then
        Location = New System.Drawing.Point(-Width * 2, -Height - 2)
        Me.Show()
        blnNachDialogVerstecken = True
    End If
    Activate()

    If MaterialDialog.Show("Neuer Historien Eintrag", objDialogContent, MaterialWinforms.Controls.MaterialDialog.Buttons.OKCancel, MaterialDialog.Icon.Info) = DialogResult.OK Then
        Objekt.HistorieSpeichern(objDialogContent.Ergebniss)
    End If

    If blnNachDialogVerstecken Then
        Me.Hide()
        Location = objOldLocation
    End If

End Sub
```

In here the first modal Form, so a MessageBox.Show("") or any other form closes Instantly if i don't do the show and activate part. 
What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Why the HeadsUp.Close statement?

Comment: because i dont need to display It any longer

Comment: I guess I am confused by your code/question..nvm

Answer (score 0):

Project > (Project) Properties > Application > Shutdown mode

change from when startup form closes to when last form closes

Comment: But my Application doesn´t closes, only the dialog does.